# How to print this string properly in Perl?

Tags: perl

I want to print out this string:

```
[2/16/2012] emailed...I honestly do not know - I am an endpoint in sales - I would try contacting our corporate office. <STOP>
```

When I try to print this string, this is what it looks like in the terminal:

```
[2/16/2012] emailed...I honestly do not know û I am an endpoint in sales û I would try contacting our corporate office. <STOP>
```

How do I get the terminal to print "-" characters instead of "û" characters?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The terminal is trying to use the OEM code page (typically 437 or 850), in which character 151 is indeed a ù. You need to do two things:

1. Change the console to use a Unicode font, instead of raster fonts (which always use the OEM code page)
2. Change the code page to (say) 1252

Comment: On the DOS terminal, I can only select Lucida font instead of Raster fonts. There doesn't seem to be an option for changing the code page. How do I do this?

Answer (score 0):

You might try to change the encoding of STDOUT, by something like:

```
use encoding 'utf8', STDOUT => 'cp850'; # or 'cp1252', change to what your terminal needs
```

What system do you use, and what locale is set? You may start with just `use encoding 'utf8';` as well.

The other way around is replacing these pesky characters with simple dashes. There are many ways to do it, `$string_to_print =~ tr/$pesky_character/-/` is probably the best.

Comment: I tried this (both cp850 and cp1252) and I get this error: "\x{fffd}" does not map to cp1252